# Is there a better way to handle typescript Partial constructor

Tags: typescript

Setting up some type script classes and just wondering if there is a better way to structure the Partial constructor to accommodate for a couple of different input types.

In principle I want the TextBlock class to always output TextModel and a RichText or null. But for the constructor to take either a string, RichText or null. If the user passes a string into the constructor for it to convert it to a RichText via its constructor.

The best way I have found to deal with this is to create an interface that for this input can have any of the 3 types, but the class to only have the 2 types. This keeps the output type safe but allows me to pass multiple types into the constructor.

```
interface TextBlockModel
{
    textModel : RichText | string | null;
}

export class TextBlock
{
    textModel: RichText | null = null;

    constructor(source? : Partial<TextBlockModel> | null)
    {
        Object.assign(this, source);

        this.textModel = new RichText(source?.textModel);
        console.log("textblock", source)
    }
}
```

There may not be a nicer way to do this, but just wondering if there is. I have striped the code down to highlight the questions use case. If it was just this 1 variable would not use the partial constructor.

Comment: A few questions: 1. Does `TextBlockModel` have other properties? 2. Is it really correct to pass `undefined` into `new RichText` when `source` isn't provided or is `null`? 3. Is it really correct to pass a `RichText` into `new RichText` (when `source` is provided and `source.textModel` is a `RichText`)?

Comment: From a correctness perspective, I'd be leery of `Object.assign(this, source);` because A) `source` might have properties that `TextBlock` isn't supposed to have, and B) `source`'s `textModel` might be a `string`, while `TextBlock`'s `textModel` is defined to not be a string. Granted, it's only a string *briefly*, but that would bother me. (For that second part I'd do `const { textModel, ...rest} = source ?? {}; Object.assign(this, rest);` since you handle `textModel` later.)

Comment: TextBlockModel and TextBlock both have additional properties, if it was just the 1 I could adjust the constructor to not take a Partial but to take particular variables and then handle the types via that. what im wanting to avoid if i can is creating a constructor with many parameters that need to be entered event when just handling a string and having to pass null in for all the other. The RichText does handle the null within itself if undefined/null is passed though to return null (which in tern the js handles to hide/show elements)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I edited a third question into my first comment. :-)

Comment: No worries,  While im thinking of adding is an if check, so if the source.textModel is already a RichText, then to not bother with the conversation as its duplicated effort that is not then required.

Comment: *(Messed up this comment, deleted and reposted.)* Sorry, another question: Other than `textModel`, are `TextBlock` and `TextBlockModel` the same shape (other than methods on `TextBlock`)? That is, is `TextBlockModel` **just** for dealing with `textModel` being possibly a string?

Comment: This is correct yes, Ideally id love to get rid of TextBlockModel as its not required/needed anywhere else in the application, but is just allow me to pass a string though prior to conversation without throwing errors/enabling TextBlock.textMode to be considered as a string.

Comment: Have implemented the feedback on the ...rest now as well. This makes much more sense that having to assign the whole object and then re-assign a variable shortly after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it's *simpler*, but since `TextModelBlock` is just derived from `TextModel` but without methods and with a slightly-adjusted type for `textModel`, I'd probably do that with a mapped type:

```typescript
// (Utility type)
type WithoutFunctions<T> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends Function ? never : T[Key];
};
type TextBlockOptions = WithoutFunctions<Omit<TextBlock, "textModel">> & {
    textModel?: TextBlock["textModel"] | string;
};
```

Then the constructor's parameter is `source?: TextBlockOptions | null`.

That way, changes to `TextBlock` automatically show up in the parameter's type (you don't have to edit them in parallel), and even if you add a further element to the union of types for `textModel`, it still comes through in the parameter's type.

I'd also tweak the constructor's implementation slightly to handle the case where `textModel` is already a `RichText` as discussed in the comments, and to avoid assigning `textModel` to `this` when it's still a string:

```typescript
export class TextBlock {
    textModel: RichText | null = null;

    constructor(source?: TextBlockOptions | null) {
        const { textModel, ...rest } = source ?? {};
        // (I'm always leery of doing this Object.assign thing)
        Object.assign(this, rest);

        if (source?.textModel instanceof RichText) {
            this.textModel = source.textModel;
        } else {
            this.textModel = new RichText(source?.textModel);
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAoCkFcGcBdQENQKQOwCYFoCW6BKAKAGMAbJWWUAJVxIAsAVAUwA9EBvI0X0EgPboEAJ2gl4AkeAAO0AEZl6oAfIBWLCQH4AXLXrN2iAD6p4I-AHNQp9NDJkCobn1ABfIh6LwAnjJagAOq48AwC0PAAYtDoErhCsAA8TAB8oAC8zjx8ANoA0iw+oPigANaFAgBmoEwAunpM+YW1oEYsWNTRsfDx6KBaoOgsAG4sIqANTT61ANyec77+NUYAQmQCJKUA8jI9CRlBIWERXXEJiVsAtiHJq+ubADSgAETwRgCyApgsZM8paQAyLKuN4cT7fMi6ZYcNYbUo5V4fL4-Z4tUyiKxzNxzIjsGRSRDkSjUVgw+6lYF8UHwcE-PR0RikkyDexkA52Bw41yCYTmcSSaSwcIiEgsKFM2GbHZ7YQ2FkOJwuVx8HkIZygam0shPAB0epELDVbgOQugIoCWgGnGx2WVoBAEAAkgByS7IMgAdyQPmoZBYYyKVVAmAEVg1DFw1C26k08B1xNwlj6oSsxDtvGjGgk8aoifQ4BTsCeBoQBC56dw1XApvNWh1muRbPwaFiLCDDMMHEVtvTvEL9aREJNwtFA7BjbmveNP1gASVvb7EdgY5pjfZLA9+kZRmrI7FK61ZZ7rg8J88RCIQ03EvJ4E4DYhemelQEAmebjLC-TDsCUlKsEvDdoXgSVSjvB86UGICOyZcBn1fZ4CA-GZeB-P8AKvYDQPAwdII5MhkK-b8wF-ER-0A687jhO9CKIujezQsiMKAm9qM-eiOLtRjyMw1jNhw8dH1AAAWAAmWjONQsAAFERBEKRkGob5YFwA1MCIIA)

---

Re `Object.assign(this, source)` (or `Object.assign(this, rest)`): I don't like doing that because `source` can have properties that `TextBlock` and TypeScript don't know about:

```
const stuff = { textModel: "Nifty", unrelated: 42 };
const tb = new Textblock(stuff);
// Now `tb` has an `unrelated` property that TypeScript doesn't know about
```

This can have unintended consequences.

For that reason, I always passlist the things being assigned to `this`. There are various ways to do it. When you know the properties exist on the target, a utility function like this does it:

```typescript
function assignValid<T>(target: T, ...sources: Partial<T>[]): T {
    for (const source of sources) {
        for (const key of Object.keys(source)) {
            if (key in target) {
                (target as any)[key] = (source as any)[key];
            }
        }
    }
    return target;
}
```

Yes, those `any` type assertions are ugly, but they're implied in `Object.assign` anyway.

Then use `assignValid(this, rest);` instead of `Object.assign(this, rest);`.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAoCkFcGcBdQENQKQOwCYFoCW6BKAKAGMAbJWWUAJVxIAsAVAUwA9EBvI0X0EgPboEAJ2gl4AkeAAO0AEZl6oAfIBWLCQH4AXLXrN2iAD6p4I-AHNQp9NDJkCobn1ABfIh6LwAnjJagAOq48AwC0PAAYtDoErhCsAA8TAB8oAC8zjx8ANoA0iw+oPigANaFAgBmoEwAunpM+YW1oEYsWNTRsfDx6KBaoOgsAG4sIqANTT61ANyec77+NUYAQmQCJKUA8jI9CRlBIWERXXEJiVsAtiHJq+ubADSgAETwRgCyApgsZM8paQAyLKuN4cT7fMi6ZYcNYbUo5V4fL4-Z4tUyiKxzNxzIiVGJnPqUWC4SzoABqSCUmGSKXA8CQIksLHgDSeADoObBwiISCxYHoAAoMnqUmk5WoEBrAviVKQQQTCRBc6A8gJVVDc3mwJwuVwyuXgBUIMqFFTVLbqTTwNnlHywcDK1UEHXZPV63DVcC24p9emM5kut1Bvh0hlMxCUZDoHwEHK2lqZB2agKRjAxuPNObB1weYO5vj53giZkq31h5lYohEdgyKSIchE6HwWGbaW8UHwcE-PR0RisDg2Qb2MgHOwOHGuI3mcSSaSO3lQ-vN+7bXa9ai2YeBoNT5ygDtdsjsjnF41uA7zgJaAacbGuvVEknkym4TB0hi4WBPU-wAgToMehAl5aGyB7IiO+BoLELDqr2hgcNu2b7h+sCgUiEIXsmaFguBWZBuePywAEupIaEn7YZ24GjiwADu+h9kYSYqguFGHn+945veHheEMdFLi2pTgJwYEQnozyygIzxuH+SFuiAQRSKUsBELxTYCUJIndoMtH0fB8DgOJAiSQQ0kzLw8mBIpymqfxK4aehWljmQpmyXJYCWSISkqTptlwkJLmuYFbkKZ51k+XcfkyUF0WuBZVneXxEWbPZOGiaAAAsABMAUxaA8kAKIiCIcqRt8xLFpgRBAA)